# How can I remote desktop connect to my Windows 8.1 computer if I am not on my home network, and I don't have a separate private VPN server?

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop, openvpn

The really nice thing about Windows' Remote Desktop connection application is that it shows my remote computer's screen on my laptop at the laptop display's resolution. That's beautiful.

The downside of Windows' Remote Desktop connection application is that I can't use it to connect to my remote computer if I am not on the same local area network as it.

**Now, I might be wrong about this, but I believe that in order to use Windows' Remote Desktop when not on my home network, I should set up a VPN.**

I tried out TeamViewer's remote desktop connection ability, but it had the massive downside of not providing a usable desktop resolution on my laptop. Plus, there was a lot of extra toolbars and dialog buttons to click. It was a little annoying.

I don't have a separate machine lying around right now that I can use to act as some sort of VPN server, so I think I am looking for a solution where the server is running on the remote computer I want to connect to itself. So, having a simple one client to one server solution is good enough for me.

OpenVPN has a [Static Key Mini-HOWTO](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/78-static-key-mini-howto.html). Is this what I could/should be using to get what I want? I am not extremely hardcore on security (I just do math and science stuff, who would want to hack me?), but a little worried about it. I mean, I'd like to make sure I at least have a reasonably secure password check for connecting onto the VPN.

**What's a good solution for my needs?**

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't need to use a VPN. You just need to forward a port in your router, to the target computer. But another layer of encryption can't hurt.

Comment: You should check at least if your router (if you only use a modem scrap that) offers you VPN functionality. Most routers allow you to set up dynamic dns updates so that you can always connect to it with the same name from the internet. in Short: set up DynDNS + VPN on your router to be able to connec to your PC securely. Portforwarding is less secure since vulnerabiilities in the RDP stack can be used by crackers to hack your PC.

Answer (score 0):

You have to meet couple of conditions before you can RDP into your PC via internet.

1. WIndows 8.1 Pro at the minimum on the system you will be connecting to
2. Static IP or DynDNS with dynamic IP address.

You can refer to the guide here for more info on setting it up: http://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/configure-router-for-remote-desktop/

I had exactly same question as you and this is what I found out. Finishing setting up the target system and hopefully will be RDPing home soon from elsewhere... anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked on a similar problem, but one where security was more a concern.

Upgrading to windows pro will allow you to click a few buttons to set up a server, but it seems that people are quite wary about the security.  Plus, you have to upgrade to pro.

openVPN point to point static key is not too terribly hard to set up.  I took a quick read through the "networking all in one for dummies" book, and also a few command line and batch file tutorials online, and that was all I needed to understand how to set it up.  Port forwarding and no ip for openVPN are pretty easy; in fact, no ip customer support will help you with it, for free!  (Or at least, they helped me after I badgered them a little).

Here is my situation and my solution:

[Windows 10 Pro networking: allowing users to remotely access accounting software on a laptop; security and conceptual questions before testing](https://superuser.com/questions/1215884/windows-10-pro-networking-allowing-users-to-remotely-access-accounting-software)